# where to store information about routes and points?

Tags: mysql, leaflet, openstreetmap, geojson

I'm working on a project where I need to display maps. These maps are going to have routes and points of interest, there will be many maps to display in the future. At this moment, the project operates with mysql. At first, I was thinking in keeping the points of interest and the points from the routes in a table in mysql server and display them with leaflet.js and OSM, but doing some research I found information about geoJson to store points and routes, and also i notice that leaflet can display information in geojson format.

I am a novice at Maps topic, so what do you recommended me?

- To store points in mysql?
- To have a database of geoJson files which store information about any map?

The project is about a Web application where the user will find detailed information about some routes, this information will be displayed in text format(html) and will be accompanied with a map (that will display the route and some points)

Answer (score 0):

We (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.aph.avigenie&hl=en) used a sqlite DB on the device to store favourites. We also store OSM (Open Street Maps) data in MySQL.  Having the geospatial extensions is helpful; however, we don't use them, we have been able to find ways around having them.

Comment: uh, no, just offering some credibility to my answer... I do this stuff!  BTW that app is for the blind, not a general audience.

Comment: i'm thinking that i have to check more information about "geospatial extensions", thank for your answer

Answer (score 0):

A *really* useful answer would require some more insights about your application. For example, is your application somehow coupled with a webservice? Is your application itself a web service? In that case, should the various calculation be performed on client-side or server-side?  Are you dealing with few POI and routes having not many waypoints? Or are you working on a planetary GIS?

Assuming you probably are somewhere between those last two extremes, you should definitively take a look at:

- [MySQL spatial extension](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/spatial-extensions.html)
- or preferably [PostGIS](http://postgis.net/)

Those will allow you to store lots of data and to efficiently retrieve them.

BTW, remember the earth is not flat. So, storing point is one thing, but displaying them on a *flat* display will require to use [some kind of projection](http://maps.unomaha.edu/Peterson/gis/notes/MapProjCoord.html). [GeoJSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoJSON) itself is only a *file format*. You will definitively require a *tool* than can handle that for you. That will be one key feature to check, I think.

Comment: thank you for your answer, actually my needs are more simple, this project it's only a web application where we need to display a map with routes and some points. But i'm going to see the information and links that you recommend to see